# Return empty list if the input ListArray is empty [delete]

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to return an empty ListNode if the input ListArray is empty.

the ListNode class is :

```
public  class ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode next;
  ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
  }
```

and the function to return empty Listnode when the input is `[]` and output should be `[]` , is :

```
public  ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {
    if(lists == null)     // this is not the case, because an empty list is there
        return null;
    if(lists.length == 0)    
        return lists[0];   //this won't work because there's nothing at the 0th index
        return null; // won't work because I want to return an empty ListNode
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by "empty ListNode" . You can return `new Listnode(0)`  or `new ListNode()`

Comment: Thanks! I got a hint from your answer. Basically if I use `new ListNode()` then it'll return an error stating integer expected. but `new ListNode(0).next` worked!

Comment: `new ListNode(0).next` is null because you did not initialize `next`. See answer for more info.

Comment: I have already upvoted the answer. But it'll not be shown because I don't have enough credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what do you mean by "empty ListNode" . 
You can return `new Listnode(0)` or `new ListNode()`.
For the later you'll need to define the appropriate constructor:

```
ListNode() { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public  ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {
      if(lists.length == 0)    
          //This will return an ListNode array of length 0. i.e. []
          return new ListNode[0];
    }
```

Comment: This will return ListNode with value 0. And that's not the case. The Node should have no value.